# jQuery help: How can i hide divisions?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div id="rightside">
    <div id="rightsideone" >
         <div class="class_color_title" ></div>
         <div id="id_color_archive" ></div>
    </div>
    <div id="rightsidetwo">
         <div class="class_color_title" ></div>
         <div id="id_color_mostcomments" ></div>
    </div>
    <div id="rightsidethree">
         <div class="class_color_title" ></div>
         <div id="id_color_mostviewed" ></div>
    </div>
    <div id="rightsidefour">
        <div class="class_color_title" ></div>
        <div id="id_color_categories" ></div>           
    </div>
    <div id="rightsidefive" > 
        <div class="class_color_title" ></div>
        <div id="id_color_tags" ></div>
    </div>
    <div id="rightsidesix" >
        <div class="class_color_title" ></div>
        <div id="id_color_polls" ></div>
    </div>      
</div>
```

I want to hide divisions with id_color_* .

How can i do this ?

Comment: What do you want to know how to select?  The second next, third next, or the potentially infinite number of divs to follow?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/GiDc1Cnh  I want to hide all divs with id="id_color_*" after fourth divs when page loads loads.

How can i do this ?

Comment: Every time you duplicate an Id John Stamos kills a kitten

Comment: @Sinetheta I don't see any duplicate ids.

Comment: John Stamos killed a kitten anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to hide them after the fourth occurrence, you can do this:

```
$(function() {
  $("[id^=id_color_]").slice(4).hide();
})
```

Comment: The selector selects everything with an id beginning with "id_color_". The slice then cuts out the first 4 elements. See http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ and http://api.jquery.com/slice/

Comment: Is this correct too ? $("div [id^=id_color_]").slice(4).hide();

Comment: Yes, but remove the space between div and opening bracket (eg, div[id...).

Comment: Why ? what's the problem with space ?

Comment: The space indicates descendants, it would select ANY element with an id beginning with "id_color_" inside a DIV. Instead, you want you select ONLY divs with an id beginning with "id_color_". Both will work with your code, because you have divs nested inside other divs. But it's important to understand how the selector works and what the difference is.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('div[id^="id_color_"]').hide()
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uLa6k/

Comment: Is this correct too ? $("div [id^=id_color_]").slice(4).hide();

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#rightsidefour ~ div div[id^='id_color_']").hide();
```

See [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3fGCR/1/) for a live example.

**Explanation**

This selector means select all divs with an id that starts with `id_color_` which are descendant from another div that's a [next sibling](http://api.jquery.com/next-siblings-selector/) of `#rightsidefour`.

Comment: Is this correct too ? $("div [id^=id_color_]").slice(4).hide();

Comment: Yes. You can try it in the fiddle and see for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. It will hide all the div's which start with `id_color_` after 4th div.

```
$('div[id^="id_color_"]:gt(3)').hide();
```

Comment: I like this better than mine :p

Comment: Is this correct too ? $("div [id^=id_color_]").slice(4).hide();

Answer (score 0):

Just add "anyClass" as the class attribute for the divs you want to hide, and then simply :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".anyClass").hide();
});
```

Comment: No, i want to do this after the fourth div

Answer (score 0):

The following jQuery will work with your "new" html.
A) NEVER duplicate IDs
B) If multiple objects have something in common, that is exactly what classes are designed for.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.colour').hide()
});
```

But you should probably change the html to look a little more like.

```
<div class="rightside">
    <div id="rightsideone" >
         <div class="class_color_title" ></div>
         <div class="colour" id="id_color_archive" ></div>
    </div>
    <div class="rightsidetwo">
         <div class="class_color_title" ></div>
         <div class="colour" id="id_color_mostcomments" ></div>
    </div>
    <div class="rightsidethree">
         <div class="class_color_title" ></div>
         <div class="colour" id="id_color_mostviewed" ></div>
    </div>
    <div class="rightsidefour">
        <div class="class_color_title" ></div>
        <div class="colour" id="id_color_categories" ></div>           
    </div>
    <div class="rightsidefive" > 
        <div class="class_color_title" ></div>
        <div class="colour" id="id_color_tags" ></div>
    </div>
    <div class="rightsidesix" >
        <div class="class_color_title" ></div>
        <div class="colour" id="id_color_polls" ></div>
    </div>      
</div>
```

Comment: I want to hide after fourth div

Comment: If you actually mean what you just said then you can use either nth-of-type or nth-child selectors through jQuery or CSS. But I'm guessing that "I want to hide after fourth div" is a simplistic explanation of what you're trying to do. Please, err on the side of specificity, it saves everyone having to repeat over and over again MORE INFORMATION PLEASE.